# Is there a way to use lists in a sympy expression?

Tags: python, math, sympy

I'm trying to use sympy to work with some optimization functions but I need a way to insert lists

```
l=[.5, .2, .8, .7, .3]

Sum((l[k] - f(k))**2, (k,0,4))
```

I was able to do this in desmos and I'm wondering if I can do this in sympy as well

Comment: please give a minimum reproducible example

Comment: `sum((x - f(k))**2 for k,x in enumerate(l))` or `sum((l[k] - f(k))**2 for k in range(len(l)))`. This is not specific to sympy, it's basic python syntax. See the documentation for [builtin functions: `sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [tutorial: generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)

Comment: Are these sympy optimization functions, or other (like scipy).  I think the question needs more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stef answer is solid. However, if you have to use SymPy (maybe you don't know yet what `f` is), or you want to apply some other symbolic computation, this is how you'd do it:

```py
from sympy import *
k = symbols("k")
f = Function("f")
l = IndexedBase("l")
list_values = Array([.5, .2, .8, .7, .3])

s = Sum((l[k] - f(k))**2, (k, 0, 4))
print(s)
# Sum((-f(k) + l[k])**2, (k, 0, 4))
```

```py
s = s.subs(l, list_values)
print(s)
# Sum((-f(k) + [0.5, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 0.3][k])**2, (k, 0, 4))
```

```py
print(s.doit())
# (0.2 - f(1))**2 + (0.3 - f(4))**2 + (0.5 - f(0))**2 + (0.7 - f(3))**2 + (0.8 - f(2))**2
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
sum((x - f(k))**2 for k,x in enumerate(l))
```

or

```py
sum((l[k] - f(k))**2 for k in range(len(l)))
```

This is not specific to sympy, it's basic python syntax.

See the documentation for [builtin functions: `sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [tutorial: generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)

Comment: I need the syntax for sympy so I can take its derivative later

Comment: @Dimitris02 This python construction does create a sympy expression, provided that `f(k)` only uses sympy functions. You can take derivates etc..  But note that sympy doesn't work together with scipy or numpy functions, and that sympy dislikes floats as it tries to find exact symbolic solutions.